# How can I get current time by using a static method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I couldn't get current time by using static method, How can I imporve my method to get current time?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Console.WriteLine(timeNow.TimeNow);
    }
}

public class timeNow
{
    public static string TimeNow
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:MM:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

I motified code for easier to test, What I got is wrong current time, For example, right now is 11/29/2018  09:52 in my time zone. What I got from this code is 2018/11/29  09:11:25.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, can you provide the real code and not a fake?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can be less verbose with this syntax (works the same): `public static string TimeNow => DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:MM:ss");`

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: Is your class named `XXXX`? Just making a correction, `TimeNow` is a **property** and not a method (since you are using the `get` accessor construct).

Comment: you tagged this w/ wpf - do you want to make a clock?

Comment: Are you trying to use this in a wpf binding, and expect it to update/refresh as time ticks?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 This code is used to write a Log for my application.

Comment: Change your `.ToString()` to this `.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss")` (notice the small `m` for minutes - you used big `M` which stands for the month) or use `.ToString("g")`

Comment: @RandRandom You are right ! ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss");
```

Issue was with the "HH:MM:ss".  It was "MM" which is month. Refer [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) for details on format strings